# How to remove a word from str in list in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to remove all `<start>` and `<end>` from a dictionary as:

```py
my_dict = {1:['<start> the woman is slicing onions <end>',
       '<start> a woman slices a piece of onion with a knife <end>',
       '<start> a woman is chopping an onion <end>',
       '<start> a woman is slicing an onion <end>',
       '<start> a woman is chopping onions <end>',
       '<start> a woman is slicing onions <end>',
       '<start> a girl is cutting an onion <end>'],
      2: ['<start> a large cat is watching and sniffing a spider <end>',
            '<start> a cat sniffs a bug <end>',
            '<start> a cat is sniffing a bug <end>',
            '<start> a cat is intently watching an insect crawl across the floor <end>',
            '<start> the cat checked out the bug on the ground <end>',
            '<start> the cat is watching a bug <end>',
            '<start> a cat is looking at an insect <end>'],
      3:['<start> a man is playing a ukulele <end>',
         '<start> a man is playing a guitar <end>',
         '<start> a person is playing a guitar <end>',]}
```

Comment: Iterate through the dictionary, iterate through the list, remove / replace what needs to be changed. What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```py
my_dict = {k : [s.replace("<start>", "").replace("<end>", "") for s in l] for k, l in my_dict.items() }
```

You may want to add a `strip()` after the second replace to get rid of the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.replace` to replace `<start>`/`<end>` with an empty string:

```py
my_dict = {
    1: [
        "<start> the woman is slicing onions <end>",
        "<start> a woman slices a piece of onion with a knife <end>",
        "<start> a woman is chopping an onion <end>",
        "<start> a woman is slicing an onion <end>",
        "<start> a woman is chopping onions <end>",
        "<start> a woman is slicing onions <end>",
        "<start> a girl is cutting an onion <end>",
    ],
    2: [
        "<start> a large cat is watching and sniffing a spider <end>",
        "<start> a cat sniffs a bug <end>",
        "<start> a cat is sniffing a bug <end>",
        "<start> a cat is intently watching an insect crawl across the floor <end>",
        "<start> the cat checked out the bug on the ground <end>",
        "<start> the cat is watching a bug <end>",
        "<start> a cat is looking at an insect <end>",
    ],
    3: [
        "<start> a man is playing a ukulele <end>",
        "<start> a man is playing a guitar <end>",
        "<start> a person is playing a guitar <end>",
    ],
}

for v in my_dict.values():
    v[:] = (s.replace("<start>", "").replace("<end>", "").strip() for s in v)

print(my_dict)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    1: [
        "the woman is slicing onions",
        "a woman slices a piece of onion with a knife",
        "a woman is chopping an onion",
        "a woman is slicing an onion",
        "a woman is chopping onions",
        "a woman is slicing onions",
        "a girl is cutting an onion",
    ],
    2: [
        "a large cat is watching and sniffing a spider",
        "a cat sniffs a bug",
        "a cat is sniffing a bug",
        "a cat is intently watching an insect crawl across the floor",
        "the cat checked out the bug on the ground",
        "the cat is watching a bug",
        "a cat is looking at an insect",
    ],
    3: [
        "a man is playing a ukulele",
        "a man is playing a guitar",
        "a person is playing a guitar",
    ],
}
```